# Parse for Android Simple select query

Tags: java, android, select, android-studio, parse-platform

In my database in parse.com I have a table with hotels (name, city, address), 
For example: HiltonHotel, London, Baker Str 11
I want to select city (in example "London"). How to ask query to find it?

Answer (score 0):

A simple query:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Hotels"); //DB class
query.whereEqualTo("city", "London");
```

Column, Value = Here you filter your rows, so you can have a list of hotels in London (It's like SQL). You can add as many filters as you like:

```
query.whereContains("name","Hilton");
```

Now let's go on. Here you retrieve the results / rows and set a Callback to see, whether you have found any rows or not. Here though, you check whether everything is alright, maybe you have typed in a wrong class, maybe something else. In that case e will be not be null and you will be able to control it.

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
public void done(List<ParseObject> object, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
        //Retrievement successful, you could create a list from that.
    } else {
        //Error, nice hint: 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext,"Error: "+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
});
```

Here you find more information how you can build a simple listview of these resulting rows: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-listview-tutorial/